# Scout-App: Ignore some files

Tags: css, sass

I want to ignore some file in Scout-App (SASS).

[image: sass_hierarchy]

All the files are converted to .css when I save them. 
Is it possible to avoid the conversion?

I just want to do this in "style.sass":

```
@import "general"
@import "alerts"
@import "singleForm"
@import "navbar"
```

and to have a file "style.css" with the complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add an underscore before the file name it should be ignored like so:

Your file: filename.sass

Converted file: _filename.sass

> If you have a SCSS or Sass file that you want to import but don't want
>   to compile to a CSS file, you can add an underscore to the beginning
>   of the filename. This will tell Sass not to compile it to a normal CSS
>   file. You can then import these files without using the underscore.

[Source](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)